# Regex to match certain words but not others

Tags: regex, perl

I am working with regexes in perl, and I'm trying to make a regex that finds two words where one ends with d and the next word starts with p (but not ph). Here is my regex, which works:

```
d\s(p[^h])}
```

However, I'd also like this to exclude the word "and" (but only within this pattern) so I have tried to use a negative lookahead, so my code looks like this:

```
if ($text =~ m{d\s(p[^h])} && $text =~ m{(?:(?!\sand\s))}) {
        print "Yes\n";
        } else {
                }
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

Here are some sample input/output:

sand pet -> yes

sand phone -> no

go and pet -> no

sand pet and -> yes

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you need with a single regex:

```
/(?<!\ban)d\s(p[^h]\w+)/
```

Where:

- `\b` is the word boundary anchor, doesn't consume any chars but assure that the excluded words is `and` and not `sand`. It matches between `\w` (word chars: [a-zA-Z0-9_]) and `\W` (not in word chars) and in the same position of `^` and `$`.
- `(?<!\ban)d` a `d` not preceded by an *isolated* `an`, technically speaking is almost equivalent to `(?<!\Wan)`.

Online [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB1iG5/2)

If you doesn't need to extract the first and second word separately you may remove the capturing groups also and add some tolerance (one or more spaces between words):

```
if ( $input =~ m/(?<!\ban)d\s+p(?!h)/ )
  print "Yes\n";
else
  print "No\n";
```

**Note**: this regex is actually search for a `d` (not preceded by a non-substring `an`) separated by one or more spaces from a `p` not followed by a `h`. It tells nothing aboud *words*. If you want to make sure there are words of more than one char you can add a leading and trailing `\w+`.

Another [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB1iG5/3)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting too complicated. That negative lookahead is applied to the string, and matches against any substring. So it will match any *substring* which doesn't contain `\sand\s` which is always going to work, because zero length substrings are 'ok'.

You can see this at work with turning on debugging:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use re 'debug';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    print if m{(?:(?!\sand\s))};
}

__DATA__
sand pet 
sand phone 
go and pet 
sand pet and
empty
```

That lookahead is used with another pattern to say 'match this, but only if this is (or isn't) next'.

So something like:

```
m{d\s(p[^h])} and not m{\sand\s};
```

Might do what you want - or alternatively, just break it down into phases:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#use re 'debug';

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($capture) = m{d\s(p[^h])};
    if ( $capture and not $capture =~ m/\sand\s/ ) {
        print $capture, " => ", $_, "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
sand pet 
sand phone 
go and pet 
sand pet and
empty
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often inappropriate to try to get everything working in a single regex. This program has a subroutine `ok_words` that checks a pair of words to see if your criteria apply. The calling code takes every pair of words in the string and prints a `yes` if the test is true for any pair, otherwise `no`

These are your tests, together with the Perl code that checks for them

- The first ends in a `d` — `/\d\z/`
- ...but isn't `and` — `ne 'and'
- The second starts with a `p`, but not `ph` — `/\Ap(?!h)/`

And this is the program that applies them

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::MoreUtils qw/ any /;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;

    my @w = split;

    if ( any { ok_words( $w[$_], $w[$_+1] ) } 0 .. $#w-1 ) {
        print "$_ -> yes\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$_ -> no\n";
    }

}

sub ok_words {
    my ($this, $next) = map lc, @_;

    $this =~ /d\z/ and $this ne 'and' and $next =~ /\Ap(?!h)/;
}

__DATA__
sand pet
sand phone
go and pet
sand pet and
```

#### output

```
sand pet -> yes
sand phone -> no
go and pet -> no
sand pet and -> yes
```

Comment: @bobblebubble: How is that relevant to my post?